# Change summernote widget value explicitly using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, summernote

I am currently using summernote(wysiwyg) widget. I want to update the value of the widget explicitly from some place in the code using jquery, which I couldn't do currently. We can do this by catching the events keyup, enter etc., But I want this to happen exclusively with jquery from some point that to from some place of my code.

For example: I want some kind of `$("summernote selector").val("Take this new value");`

Is there any way to do this. I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but is this what you are after?

```
var sHTML = 'text';
$('summernote selector').code(sHTML);
```